# How can you determine if Y.add has been called for a YUI3 module?

Tags: javascript, module, yui, yui3

I want to determine at runtime whether a YUI module has been defined (i. e. whether someone has called YUI.add() for that module).

Based on reading the YUI code, it seems like YUI.Env.mods[moduleName] will do the trick, but I can't find any documentation for this property so I'm not sure if it's meant to be used/works in all cases. Is there a preferred way to do this?

EDIT: here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

We are switching from a system where most assets are manually loaded via link/script tags in the HEAD to one where we depend more on the YUI loader. To support legacy code, I want to make sure that modules preloaded in the HEAD will not get loaded again by YUI (some things like jQuery have issues when loaded twice).

The preloaded modules are a mix of YUI-style and non-YUI-style modules.

So far, I'm emitting code like the following:

```
<head>
<!-- bunch of script/link tags -->
<script>
    var modules = // list of preloaded modules
        , i;
    for (i = 0; i < modules.length; ++i) {
        if (!ISMODULEALREADYDEFINED(modules[i])) {
            YUI.add(modules[i], function (Y) { }, '');
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
```

The reason I need the ISMODULEALREADYDEFINED check is that if some of the pre loaded modules are YUI-style modules, then YUI might still be loading up their dependencies asynchronously when we run the above script. If that happens, then the noop module definition I'm adding prevents the original module definition callback from ever running.

Comment: object detection works in most situations like this.

Comment: @dandavis: in this case, I only know the module name, not which types/functions it might define.

Comment: Can you be more precisely on what are you actually trying to do? I'm a bit confused. I can't see why would you need this. YUI, for example, loads it's dependencies from yui's cdn, and if a module was loaded it will not load again. So you need to define your module with YUI.add() within a js file and load it via YUI global config, or in your html file right after YUI seed file.

Comment: If YUI.add had not been called, the callback on YUI().use() doesn't get called, the application simply seems dead.  If it is for the purpose of debugging, load yui-debug.js instead of yui-min.js and it will get logged.

Comment: @user32225: are you recommending something like `var loaded = false; YUI.use(moduleName, function (Y) { loaded = true; });`?